# How to install python colorlog package in Linux

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

My python script is importing colorlog module of python but it is giving me error:-

```
ImportError: No module named colorlog
```

This definitely means that colorlog package is not installed in my linux server. When I am trying to install it using below command, that too is not working:-

```
python -m pip install colorlog
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip

python -m pip install logging
/usr/bin/python: No module named pip
```

Am I running any incorrect command here? Also, below are the Linux and Python versions I am using:-

Linux - Linux 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64

Python - Python 2.7.5

Comment: try `pip install colorlog` if you've `pip` installed already

Comment: `yum install python-pip` then try again.

Comment: BTW, you should seriously consider learning Python 3, Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020. In Python 3, pip is a standard module.

Comment: I do know python 3, but our client has approved python2.7 only to be used in their project. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you do not have `pip` installed. Try installing it first: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/. Then you should be able to install colorlog package with `pip install colorlog`.